# How to backup data from recovery screen?

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, data-recovery, realme

I am using Color OS 7 (Realme UI) on Realme 2 Pro. The phone is booted in recovery mode and I cannot start it normally.

I have some data (other than Contacts, SMS and Photos) which I would like to take a backup of.

Is it possible to take backup of data, perhaps by inserting a MicroSD card and copying the data from phone storage to that card or could I connect it to PC to take data backup?

**Software:** https://www.realme.com/in/support/software-update (Realme 2 Pro, Realme UI v1.0)

I am thinking to download the file to an SD card and try installing it from there. Will the data be lost if done so?

P.S: The bootloader is locked, I did not install TWRP also.

Comment: for RMX1801 there is [TWRP](https://twrp.me/oppo/realme2pro.html) or [Orange Fox](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4038543) available, for RMX1807 you can find [Red Wolf](https://www.google.com/search?q=RMX1807+Red+Wolf) or [R2X2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3934347) (unfortunately none of that comes with encryption support) so you are left with ColorOS recovery (which maybe can flashed from EDL mode)

Comment: maybe related: https://c.realme.com/in/post-details/1135432471341432832 and https://piunikaweb.com/2019/06/04/realme-shares-workarounds-for-realme-2-pro-bootloop-problem-after-android-pie-coloros-6-update